# Using third party libraries (js-cookie) wit manifest 3

Tags: manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, js-cookie

I have a chrome extension which will add a button to images on a website. When the button is clicked it saves the image id within a cookie. I then have a separate React application which gets the cookie and uses the image id.

I originally had my code in manifest 2 and I am updating to manifest 3. I am using js-cookie with my chrome extension and within my react application to get and set my cookies.

When using js-cookie, although the code works as it should and I am able to get the cookie to set and get, I get an error in my background.js console: 'ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined'

How am I supposed to use a library like js-cookie? I read that you can use bundlers like webpack, but my chrome extension is quite small. If possible I would like to not do that. I tried to load a script in my popup.html but still get the error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

// manifest.json

```
    {
      "name": "Chrome extension anem",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "description": "description",
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "alarms",
        "declarativeContent",
        "scripting",
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation",
      ],
      "host_permissions": [
            "*://*.hello.com/*",
      ],
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "*://*.hello.com/*",
          ],
          "js": ["node_modules/js-cookie/dist/js.cookie.js", "content.js"],
          "run_at": "document_start"
        }
      ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
            "*://*.hello.com/*",
    ]
  },
      "action": {
        "default_popup": "views/popup/popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
          "16": "icons/icon16.png",
          "32": "icons/icon32.png",
          "48": "icons/icon48.png",
          "128": "icons/icon128.png"
        }
      },
      "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "32": "icons/icon32.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
      }
    }
```

//popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../../node_modules/js-cookie/dist/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="./popup.js"></script>
    <style>
      #root {
        width: 180px;
      }
      .some-classname {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <label class="some-classname">
        &nbsp;Click
      </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

// background.js
I am using a background port within content.js for when the below are called. I did not add all code for privacy reasons.

```
const getCookie = async () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      resolve(Cookies.getJSON(lblCookie) || [])
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  });
};

const setCookie = async (cookieList) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const { tab } = await getTab();
    const url = new URL(tab.url);
    const domain = `.${url.hostname.split('.').slice(1).join('.')}`;
    try {
      resolve(Cookies.set('cookieName', cookieList, { expires: 3, domain: domain }));
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: You can't use DOM in the service worker so you can't use js-cookie which depends on DOM. Use `chrome.cookies` API directly.